# root_validator called twice for one instance

Tags: python, pydantic

```py
from typing import Any, Dict, Generic, TypeVar, get_args
import pydantic


class Mixin(pydantic.BaseModel):
    @pydantic.root_validator(pre=True)
    def print(cls, values: Dict[str, Any]):
        print(f"Validator for {cls.__name__}")
        return values


class B1(Mixin): ...
class B2(Mixin): ...
BT = TypeVar("BT", B1, B2)


class BaseModel(Generic[BT], pydantic.BaseModel):
    b: BT

    @pydantic.root_validator(pre=True)
    def fill_defaults(cls, values: Dict[str, Any]):
        b_type = get_args(cls.__orig_bases__[0])[0]
        print(f"Filling defaults for {b_type.__name__}")
        if "b" not in values:
            values["b"] = b_type()
        return values


class Model1(BaseModel[B1]): ...
class Model2(BaseModel[B2]): ...


Model2()
```

Outputs:

```bash
Filling defaults for B2
Validator for B2
Validator for B1
```

Why is `Validator for B1` printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should be using **`GenericModel`** (from `pydantic.generics`) as a base class for your custom `BaseModel` instead of `pydantic.BaseModel` as described [here in the documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/models/#generic-models). `GenericModel` is a special subclass of `BaseModel` providing additional functionality that is very useful (not to say critical) when dealing with generic field types. But this has no bearing on this specific issue you describe.

---

### TL;DR

The reason you are seeing the `B1` validator called is because you are using a **constrained** type variable as opposed to one with an **upper bound**. (See [this section of PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#generics) for the distinction.)

Replace `BT = TypeVar("BT", B1, B2)` with `BT = TypeVar("BT", bound=Mixin)` and this issue disappears.

---

### *Why* is this happening?

The reason comes down to how Pydantic (v1) constructs the actual field types, when it reads your model namespace. I would consider this an implementation detail since this is not documented anywhere, but this is how it is done as of `1.10.11`.

Specifically, for a "naked" annotation like `b: BT` the metaclass calls [`ModelField.infer`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.11/pydantic/fields.py#L485-L516) to construct the `ModelField` instance for that `b` field. That in turn passes the annotation (in this case that type variable `BT`) to the regular `ModelField` constructor, which calls the [`prepare`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.11/pydantic/fields.py#L539-L557) method, which in turn calls the `_type_analysis` method.

There you can see that [it handles `TypeVar` instances](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.11/pydantic/fields.py#L591-L597) differently depending on whether they have constraints or an upper bound defined on them. For constrained type variables it picks up those constraining types and constructs a **`Union`** of them. Thus the `type_` of that `ModelField` ultimately ends up as `Union[B1, B2]`. You can check this by running the following under your model definitions:

```py
print(Model2.__fields__["b"].type_)  # typing.Union[B1, B2]
```

And type unions are validated by checking against each of the types in order as described [here](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/types/#unions). Since `B1` comes before `B2` that is attempted first, it fails (because you already have an instance of `B2` there), and then the `B2` validation is triggered, which passes.

**Note**: This also means if you switch the order of the constraints and define `BT = TypeVar("BT", B2, B1)` that `B1` validation attempt will disappear as well because the `B2` instance will pass validation immediately.

Notice also that this happens *after* the `root_validator` on your generic base model is called. This is due to the fact that it is a `pre=True` root validator, which is obviously called *before* individual field validators.

---

Lastly, I am not sure your approach in that root validator is a good idea to begin with. It seems like you are trying to make some sort of default factory for that field, depending on what type argument was passed to the parameterized model. If you elaborate a bit more on what your intent there was, maybe I can suggest a less hacky approach.

Comment: Thanks. I refactored my actual code and now only `validator` is used.